# XLS report in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I want to generate a Excel and PDF report using ruby on rails , but I have  24,278 entries to display in both reports so it is showing an error . How to solve this error .
Controller Code - (for excel)

```
def from_date_wise_xls
    @start = params[:day]
    @end = params[:to_date]
    @present = params[:present]
    @employee_attendances = EmployeeAttendance.where(present: @present,day: @start..@end)
    respond_to do |format|
    format.xls {render template: 'employee_attendances/from_date_wise_xls.xls.erb'}
  end
end
```

(For PDF) -

```
def from_date_wise_pdf
   @start = params[:day]
    @end = params[:to_date]
    @present = params[:present]
    @employee_attendances = EmployeeAttendance.where(present: @present,day: @start..@end)

     respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.pdf do
        render :pdf => 'from_date_wise_pdf',
        layout: '/layouts/pdf.html.erb',
        :template => 'employee_attendances/from_date_wise_pdf.pdf.erb',
        :orientation      => 'Landscape', # default , Landscape
        :page_height      => 1000,
        :dpi              => '300',
        :margin           => {:top    => 10, # default 10 (mm)
                      :bottom => 10,
                      :left   => 20,
                      :right  => 20},
        :show_as_html => params[:debug].present?
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: what's the error? show us stack-trace

Comment: Rendered employee_attendances/from_date_wise_pdf.pdf.erb within layouts/pdf.html.erb (208778.6ms)
"***************[\"/home/indiba/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.9.9.3/bin/wkhtmltopdf_linux_386\", \"-q\", \"--orientation\", \"Landscape\", \"--dpi\", \"300\", \"--page-height\", \"1000\", \"--margin-top\", \"10\", \"--margin-bottom\", \"10\", \"--margin-left\", \"20\", \"--margin-right\", \"20\", \"file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20170111-4825-6ijrbc.html\", \"/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20170111-4825-1iqae2x.pdf\"]***************"

Comment: At terminal this will come and nothing comes at front-end  .